# Facet with all_terms: true on index alias

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I have an multi-tenant application that uses index aliases with filters. There is just one issue... when I use `facet('tags') { terms :tags, all_terms: true }` it returns all terms for the complete index and not the ones that match the current tenant.

Is where a simple way arround this issue (except generating an index per customer)?

Example: http://pastie.org/5400685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in how elasticsearch treats all_terms in facets on filtering aliases. But solution for your issue is simple, just remove `all_terms: true` and run your facet on the [`match_all`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-all-query.html) or `*:*` query.

Comment: Do you mean a facet filter with `match_all`?

Comment: No, I meant do what you are already doing, just remove all_terms: true. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/6aaac09bb35ea45ea209

Comment: Yes, but then you don't get the terms with 0 matches.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying now. So, you want to execute a query using filtering alias, but you want to also get terms that exist in the results limited by only by alias filter, but might have 0 hits in the result limited by both alias filter and your query. That's tricky. Not sure if it's possible to do in a single request without fixing https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2423 first. You can do it in two requests though. First, get total list of facet in alias using *:* and then get counts using your query.

Comment: yeah, thought so... too bad.